# AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) is required for connecting PDF form with java api

Tags: java, pdf, aem

I create a PDF Form  via Adobe DC, I would like to connect with my java application, but when I created the Servlet Class of my application(I follow all steps in Adobe web site) in some reference I found the AEM or the LifeCycle Adobe is required to do all this process and in other page I don't found it, so my question is: is AEM required for connect PDF form with java api ?
 if is required,can anyone provide me links needed for the installation?

Comment: What kind of form did you create? There are more than one type of PDF form. There are Acroforms, XFA Static forms and XFA dynamic forms.

Comment: PDF form with Adobe Acorbot DC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is AEM required for connect PDF form with java api?

No. Not at all. In fact, most PDF viewers, though not browsers, will allow you to submit PDF data to any URL as an HTML GET with key/value pairs as a query string. To the server, it looks just like submitting from an HTML form.

Comment: thank you for replying,but I need to render PDF file

Comment: @Charfi, if you want to create a PDF file then you may want to look at libraries that create PDF files from text. Some open source projects might be worth looking into

Comment: no when we doing a PDF form with adobe DC, we can add a submit button then render all this file

Comment: Are you saying you want to submit the entire file to the server and render it to an image after the form has been filled? That is also possible without AEM... unless the form is a dynamic XFA form created in Adobe Designer. In that, case you do need AEM to render the dynamic form to a static PDF and then optionally to an image. Though there are other 3rd party solutions available.